# WCF without IIS Service Not Starting for TCP on Intranet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am trying to create a WCF service in a WinForm with multiple console client applications. The example is to display all messages from the console applications on a tabbed winForm. I do not wish to use IIS and I am currently using NetTcpBinding as the solution will only be run on local networks.

I have created a WCF Service Library

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(UpdateResponse))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(RegisterResponse))]
public interface IFirstService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Dictionary<String, MyType> GetRecords();

    [OperationContract]
    RegisterResponse Register(string keyName, bool boolValue);

    [OperationContract]
    UpdateResponse Update(string keyName, string update);
}

[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    private bool _boolValue = true;
    private List<String> _stringList = new List<string>();

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return _boolValue; }
        set { _boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> StringList
    {
        get { return _stringList; }
        set { _stringList = value; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public enum UpdateResponse
{
    [EnumMember]
    Success = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    NotRegistered = 1
}

[DataContract]
public enum RegisterResponse
{
    [EnumMember]
    Success = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    Failed = 1
}
```

And also a WinForm application that starts the service

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (FirstService));
        _myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                 typeof (IFirstService), 
                 new NetTcpBinding(), 
                 new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9929/FirstService"));
        _myServiceHost.Open();

        _firstService = new FirstService();
    }
```

When I run the application a message is displayed saying WcfSvcHost has been hosted but more detail shows the Service has been Stopped as no end points have been defined.

I setup my client by creating an object to the service like

```
var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9929/FirstService"));
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IFirstService>(binding, address);
var firstService = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Any advice as to why the service is not starting would be great! Thank you

Comment: Can you also add the code of your app.config here?

Comment: My app.config is empty of WCF configuration as I assumed it was all taken care of by .AddServiceEndPoint

Comment: I Just tested your code and everything worked for me. Simply by creating a Console application.

Comment: Is your firewall / anti virus software blocking the port?

Comment: @Yaniv Can you upload somewhere to compare? I have tried changed the port and no change. If I use the Config editor and just do `_firstService = new FirstService();` the service successfully starts but is not working as intended.

Comment: Using app.config my client works successfully without the service running...